# How to retrieve details of a specific schedule using AWS CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-event-bridge

I list the `Name`s of my Amazon EventBridge schedules using [`list-schedules`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/scheduler/list-schedules.html):

```
aws scheduler list-schedules | jq '.Schedules[].Name'
```

It outputs: `my-schedule`. To double check, I view the name of my schedule on AWS webpage:

[image]

Yet when I try to use [`get-schedule`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/scheduler/get-schedule.html):

```
aws scheduler get-schedule --name my-schedule
```

I get the error:

```
An error occurred (ResourceNotFoundException) when calling the GetSchedule operation: Schedule my-schedule does not exist.
```

**How can I retrieve details about a specific schedule using AWS CLI?**

Comment: What is the group, if not provided as parameter in group-name, it will use default

Comment: Ooops, that fixes it. `group-name` wasn't default. If I use the correct one, `my-schedule` details are returned. Wanna add this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `--group-name` isn't used, `default` will be used as the group name. Ensure the correct schedule group name is used. For example:

```
aws scheduler get-schedule --group-name name-of-schedule-group \
                           --name name-of-schedule
```